# Break attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, attributes

I'm using PHP to generate some `<input type="text" class="date" name="date'.$i.'">` fields where $i increments through the `foreach` function I'm using. 
So I will have something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="date1">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date2">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date3">
```

I'm using jQuery `.last()` function to select the last element with class `date`, but I need to find a way to get that number from the `name` attribute after `date`. I know I need to use `.attr()` to get the name, but I don't know how to split it and get the number.

Comment: I would suggest using a `data-` attribute instead, so you get something like `<input type="text" class="date" name="date1" data-index="1">`

Comment: And how can I get that index and append it to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Regexp will return only numbers for `number` var.
 It works for any `name`.

```
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var number = name.replace(/\d+/g, "");
```

**Note:**
This works when `this`  is equal to `$(".date").last();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var name = "date1";
var number = name.replace(/date/g, '');

console.log(number);
```

It removes "date" from the string, leaving you with the number that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.date').last().attr('name').substr(4);
```

But using data- as suggested would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `$i` just increments can you simply use `.length` of the collection instead of getting attribute of `.last()`?

```
$('input.date').length //the desired value
```

Or `.length - 1`, obviously, if you start from 0.